# How to change the Microsoft account for OneDrive in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I have installed onedrive (version v2.4.13-9-g7857a50) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

After using my (test) microsoft account I want to use my "production"  microsoft account.

I did the following :
rename ~/.config/onedrive/refresh_token into refresh_token_backup and removed the originale file. After starting Onedrive it still uses my test MS-account.

Have someone a solution for me ?

rgds pvdb

Answer (score 0):

> I did the following : rename ~/.config/onedrive/refresh_token into refresh_token_backup and removed the originale file. After starting Onedrive it still uses my test MS-account.

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

This is not the correct process.

To switch accounts you need to use `onedrive --logout` to correctly log you out of your existing account, and then re-authenticate the client with your correct account.

This is the only way (and correct way) to do this.

Alternatively, use the `--confdir` option to specify a different configuration directory for each account type, so you can have:

- `onedrive --confdir ~/.config/onedrive-test-account/ <other-required-options>`
- `onedrive --confdir ~/.config/onedrive-production/ <other-required-options>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I did the following :

nt8356@cobol:~$ onedrive --logout

Configuration file successfully loaded Configuring Global Azure AD Endpoints Authorize this app visiting: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.all Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

Enter the response uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Application has been successfully authorised, however no additional command switches were provided. Please use --help for further assistance in regards to running this application.*

nt8356@cobol:~$

( I replaced the client_id and code by xx)

The result is that onedrive still uses my test microsoft account

Maybe I am doing something not correctly ?

rgds

Comment: Did you enter in your 'production' credentials when visiting the authentication URL or did the browser automatically log you in? Were you asked enter your 'production' account credentials - or did the browser 'cache' your 'test' credentials?